# What is the industry standard way of calculating and annualizing performance metrics?

Tags: risk, sharpe-ratio, beta, hedge-fund

Say I am looking at a performance report for a hedge fund manager who trades mostly equities, and they provide me a list of monthly returns for the past 5 years. What is the industry standard way to compute Sharpe ratio, alpha, and beta?

Sharpe ratio:

- Calculated off monthly returns and annualized by multiplying by $\sqrt 12$?
- Or calculated off daily log returns and annualized by multiplying by $\sqrt 252$?

Alpha & Beta:

- Calculated by performing a regression on monthly returns relative to S&P 500 I assume.
- Is alpha annualized by multiplying by 12?
- Beta does not need to be annualized, is that correct?

I am reading about a myriad of ways to compute these metrics and am wondering what most managers do.

Comment: Some funds are only marked monthly (some mark weekly or daily internally, but typically only publish monthly marks), thus Sharpe is computed off of monthly numbers. Sharpe is almost _always_ reported in annualized terms. Alpha and beta are more idiosyncratic. Alpha is often annualized because the numbers look bigger. Beta is indeed unitless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To give you an idea of industry standards for funds (although not hedge-fund specific), Morningstar and Trustnet both use monthly returns and annualize their data. See, for an example plucked at random, https://www.trustnet.com/factsheets/o/gnol/aberdeen-asia-pacific--japan-equity-i-acc. Monthly returns remain the standard because some funds only publish monthly numbers.

If you are using monthly returns, Alpha is multiplied by 12 and Beta is unchanged. A Monthly Sharpe ratio is annualized by multiplying by $\sqrt[]12$ (although you might want to read [How to annualize Sharpe Ratio?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/how-to-annualize-sharpe-ratio#2261)).

Your choice of benchmark depends on what investors are looking for from the hedge fund manager. The S&P 500 is OK if you are expecting the manager to invest in large-cap US equities, but it might not be appropriate if the manager has a different universe.

Comment: According to footnote in the provided link "Ratios are calculated on a monthly return basis, figures are annualised and the fund's sector average is used as a benchmark where applicable".